# error: no suitable method found for toString(String)

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, android-studio

I'm making a tic tac toe game. this is part of the code which checks which button has been pressed and sees if a circle or cross is in that button. if there is a circle or cross then the player has to choose another button.

The error message:

```
Error:(140, 38) error: no suitable method found for toString(String)
method Arrays.toString(long[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to long[])
method Arrays.toString(int[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to int[])
method Arrays.toString(short[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to short[])
method Arrays.toString(char[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to char[])
method Arrays.toString(byte[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to byte[])
method Arrays.toString(boolean[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to boolean[])
method Arrays.toString(float[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to float[])
method Arrays.toString(double[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to double[])
method Arrays.toString(Object[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Object[])
```

I have gotten this error but don't know whats wrong.

The code:

```
                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return Arrays.toString(Circle);
                    return Arrays.toString(Cross);
                }
```

Comment: It looks like `Circle` and/or `Cross` is a string. Why would you call `Arrays.toString()` on it? What is your goal? Can you show us some more code?

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one error.
First, there can be no two return statements!
Second, your Circle and Cross appear to be Strings but Arrays.toString() expects an array as argument!
Pls, provide whole code.